# How Can I Use the Utility Application Template targeted for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've been trying to use the Utility Application Template to create an iPad app. However there is not an option to set the device family to iPad. All the nib files are formated for iPhone. Is there any way to change this to target to iPad? Or would i be better off creating a standard view application and adding in the flipview?

I've been googling this and have not found a good explanation.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Utility app is iphone specific. With XCode you'll see two types of applicaiton projects that are device specific - the split view (iPad) and utility (iPhone).

Here is the link from apple's dev docs with more details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/100-iOS_Development_Quick_Start/development_quick_start.html